# How To Dynamically Add Elements To a JScrollPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am trying to make a GUI using Swing in Java that does the following:

When the "Add" button is pressed, a JPanel is created and fills up the whole width of the GUI. Inside the JPanel will be JLabels arranged using a FlowLayout that tell specific details (ie name, user ID, etc). Whenever the Add button is subsequently pressed, I want a new JPanel to be added right under the previous, so that the JScrollPane will activate its vertical scrollbar when necessary. Basically, I want the JScrollPane to be able to dynamically add new JPanels within it.

However, I have had several problems trying to do this. I can't figure out which LayoutManager to use for the panel within the JScrollPane. I have tried using GridlLayout, but that does not seem to work because when there are enough JPanels to cover up the whole JScrollPane, the GridLayout just creates a new column to squish in the new JPanels instead of adding it below the previous JPanel. What should I do in order to achieve this? Here are some images of what I have and an example of what I want to happen.

[image: GUI]

Here is what I want to happen:

[image: GUI Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance! :)

EDIT: Here is an example of my code that I tried with a GridLayout.

```
public Window() {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 701, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    buttonPanel.add(btnAdd);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel systemsPanel = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(systemsPanel);
    systemsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1, 0, 0)); //8 rows for now



    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        systemsPanel.add(new JButton("test"), "cell 0 " + i);
    }
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2); //Center the Frame 

}
```

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve] for the best chance of getting the best help quickly. This code would be small, self-standing, and posted here as code-formatted text with your question and not in a link. Good luck!

Comment: And GridLayout should work fine, but you're likely not using it correctly. Again, show us how you use it in your code. Also, are you sure that you don't want to use a JTable?

Comment: You're wrong there. It would show us what you're doing wrong and what assumptions you have that are not correct. Again, please show us the pertinent code. And please go through the [help] section, especially the subsection on how to ask questions on this site.

Comment: As already suggested, you should be using a `JTable`. You won't be able to position each component in the panel using the FlowLayout. That is your components will not be aligned in a column since the size of each component can be different. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: But looking at your GUI, you look to really really really want to use a JTable, one whose columns correspond to type, address, user id, and second type.

Comment: Okay, I will have to quickly recreate my implementation of the GridLayout to show you my code for it.

Also, I haven't heard of JTables, sorry. I'm still new to GUI design in Java. Would a JTable allow me to fill each row with a JPanel?

Comment: No, but it would allow you to fill each row with tabular data. Please look at the [JTable tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: In that case I won't be able to use a JTable since I still want other elements such as JButtons to be in each JPanel.

I'ved edited the OP to show the code I have that doesn't quite seem to format the way I want. I'ved used JButtons to fill up the panel instead of JPanels just for now so it's visible.

Comment: A JTable can display buttons. Please re-read the [mcve] link as you're making us (volunteers) do more work than you for this question, which is not how it should work on a volunteer site.

Comment: Sorry, I was in quite a bit of a rush as I have to leave very soon. I greatly appreciate your help though and deeply apologize for not properly reading the link. I will be sure to check out JTables and see if I can figure out how to implement them in my program. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: `I still want other elements such as JButtons` - see [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add rows of JPanels into a GUI, I would place them in a JPanel that uses a GridLayout(0, 1), or (0, 1, x, y). The 0 means a variable number of rows, the 1 is for 1 column, the x and y are vertical and horizontal gap. I'd then place this into a BorderLayout-using JPanel into the NORTH position so that the rows don't expand to fill the scrollpane's viewport as they'd otherwise want to do. I'd place this second wrapper JPanel into the JScrollPane's viewport.

After adding any components, I'd call revalidate and repaint on the container so that its layout managers will activate and place the new components correctly, and repaint to rid any dirty pixels that might be hanging around (much more important when removing components).

For example, my MCVE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AddRowA extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 650;
    private static final int PREF_H = 400;

    // JPanel to hold all rows. uses gridlayout that has 1 column and variable number
    // of rows
    private JPanel rowHolderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));

    public AddRowA() {
        // outerPanel is a wrapper or container JPanel that is 
        // held by JScrollPane's viewport that holds the rowHolderPanel in 
        // a BorderLayout.PAGE_START location, so the rows don't expand unnecessarily
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        outerPanel.add(rowHolderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outerPanel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.add(new JButton(new AddAction("Add")));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(addPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class AddAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel("Foo"));
            panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(25));
            panel.add(new JButton("Bar"));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));

            rowHolderPanel.add(panel);
            rowHolderPanel.revalidate();
            rowHolderPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add Row A");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new AddRowA());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

But then, you're better off using a JTable... for example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class AddRowB extends JPanel {
    private MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    public AddRowB() {
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.add(new JButton(new AddAction("Add")));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        add(addPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class AddAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            RowData row = new RowData("Type", "Address", "User ID");
            tableModel.addRow(row);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add Row B");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new AddRowB());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"Type", "Address", "User ID"};

    public MyTableModel() {
        super(COLUMNS, 0);
    }

    public void addRow(RowData rowData) {
        Object[] row = {
                rowData.getType(),
                rowData.getAddress(),
                rowData.getUserID()
        };
        addRow(row);
    }
}

class RowData {
    String type;
    String address;
    String userID;

    public RowData(String type, String address, String userID) {
        this.type = type;
        this.address = address;
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

}
```